# How can i use predict and expand_grid simultaneously while keeping control variables constant?

Tags: r, regression, predict, interaction

I would like to predict the values of an interaction using expand_grid. The first step i use is to run the model with the interaction alone and it works with no problem. Here is the example below:

```
dat <- data.frame(time=gl(n = 2,k = 5000),
                  y= rnorm(nrow(dat), mean=1000, sd=400),
                  a=factor(rep(c(1,2),times=5000)),
                  b=factor(rep(c(1,2),times=5000)),
                  c= rnorm(nrow(dat), mean=40, sd=10),
                  d= rnorm(nrow(dat), mean=550, sd=10))

m = lm(y ~ a*b, data=dat)
pred <- expand.grid(a= factor(1:2), b= factor(1:2))
pred$y <- predict(m,pred)
```

However, i would like to add some controls variables (`c` and `d`) for the model as follows:

```
m = lm(y ~ a*b + c + d, data=dat)
```

But then expand.grid does not work, only if i include all the variables. I am interested in the interaction, but also would like to add the controls. However, adding them in the expand.grid gives me too many scenarios to interpret. Is there any other way that is more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put the `c` and `d` variables in `expand.grid()` as constants and it should work fine.

```
dat <- data.frame(time=gl(n = 2,k = 5000),
                  y= rnorm(10000, mean=1000, sd=400),
                  a=factor(sample(1:2, 10000, replace=TRUE)),
                  b=factor(sample(1:2, 10000, replace=TRUE)),
                  c= rnorm(10000, mean=40, sd=10),
                  d= rnorm(10000, mean=550, sd=10))

m = lm(y ~ a*b, data=dat)
pred <- expand.grid(a= factor(1:2), b= factor(1:2), 
                    c=mean(dat$c), d=mean(dat$d))
pred$y_hat <- predict(m,newdata=pred)

#   a b        c       d    y_hat
# 1 1 1 39.90915 550.064 1002.733
# 2 2 1 39.90915 550.064 1006.523
# 3 1 2 39.90915 550.064 1015.462
# 4 2 2 39.90915 550.064 1007.281
```

One problem was that your `a` and `b` variables were exactly the same, so the prediction threw a warning.  I fixed that in the code below.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I have a small follow up question, i hope it's not too naive. What if the variable "c" was a factor control variable with three categories. Would i treat it as the continuous variable c=mean(dat$c), or i fix it at one category out of the three. If the latter is the case and i would like to fix at the third category, would fixing it look something like this c= factor(3) ?

Comment: You would say `c=factor(1, levels=c(1,2,3))`